Detect MacOS arm64 and x86/x64 in Java
I dont have access to a mac and I need to detect if the MacOS currently running is ARM64 or x64/x86 in java programmatically. Its going to be used to download chromedriver from chrome-for-testing.
Currently, I'm using this code to download:
String osName = System.getProperty("os.name", "").toLowerCase();
if(osName.contains("darwin") || osName.contains("mac")) {
    // FIXME: no check for ARM64 arch
    _zipName = chromeForTesting ? "chromedriver-mac-x64.zip" : "chromedriver_mac64.zip";
}


os.arch is probably worth looking at

something along the following (edited and tested on macpro)
cat GetSystemProperty.java 
public class GetSystemProperty {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String osName = System.getProperty("os.name");
        String osArch = System.getProperty("os.arch");

        System.out.println("OS name: " + osName);
        System.out.println("OS architecture: " + osArch);
    }
}

java GetSystemProperty
OS name: Mac OS X
OS architecture: x86_64

MacBook-Pro-15: glennstevenson$ 
uname -a
MacBook-Pro-15: 20.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 20.6.0: Thu Jul  6 22:12:47 PDT 2023; root:xnu-7195.141.49.702.12~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64


NB: a case-insensitive test may be wisest!
As always, test before use !

I would not call the variable osName since it is not the OS name. Also, I wonder if the x86-64 architecture will be called "amd64"; it is on a PC.
